# Problems with accessing char***

Tags: c

Im trying to access a char *** in strcasestr and it seems to have no effect
Heres the code:

```
#define NUMOFADDTYPES 5

const char* milkAdditions[] = {"Cream", "Half-and-half", "Whole-Milk", 
                   "Part-skim", "skim", "non-dairy", NULL};
const char* syrupAdditions[] = {"Vanilla", "Almond", "Raspberry", NULL};
const char* sweetenerAdditions[] = {"white-sugar", "sweetener", 
                    "Raw-cane", "honey", NULL};
const char* spiceAdditions[] = {"Cinnamon", "cardamon", NULL};
const char* alcoholAdditions[] = {"Brandy", "Rum", "Whiskey", 
                  "Aquavit", "Kahlua", NULL};

const char** additions[] = {milkAdditions, syrupAdditions, 
                sweetenerAdditions, spiceAdditions, 
                alcoholAdditions};



  char *ptr;
  int i, j;

  printf("Dump of additions[j][i]\n");
  for(j = 0; j < NUMOFADDTYPES; j++)
    {
      for(i = 0; (additions[j])[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
      printf("%d %d\t%s\n", j, i, additions[j][i]);
      if((ptr = strcasestr((additions[j])[i], string)) != NULL)
      {
        ptr += strlen((additions[j])[i]);
        getVolume(ptr);
      }
    }
```

Output is:

```
Dump of additions[j][i]
0 0 Cream
0 1 Half-and-half
0 2 Whole-Milk
0 3 Part-skim
0 4 skim
0 5 non-dairy
1 0 Vanilla
1 1 Almond
1 2 Raspberry
2 0 white-sugar
2 1 sweetener
2 2 Raw-cane
2 3 honey
3 0 Cinnamon
3 1 cardamon
4 0 Brandy
4 1 Rum
4 2 Whiskey
4 3 Aquavit
4 4 Kahlua
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Edit:

sorry didnt add

```
  char string[] = "AcceptAdditions: Cream;lots white-sugar;dash\r\n\r\n";
  getAddition(string);
```

**Solved**

Comment: Where is 'string' defined, and what is it's value?

Comment: Apparently, without knowing what is in `string`, you are making `ptr` point to the terminating NUL byte of each matching addition ... not sure if that' s what you want...

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add what string is, have edited it now.

Comment: What effect are you expecting? Whatever it is, it would have to be in getVolume, which you didn't post.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *strcasestr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);
```

The strcasestr() function finds the first occurrence of the substring needle in the string haystack.

So, isn't it need to be

```
strcasestr(string, (additions[j])[i])
```

instead of

```
strcasestr((additions[j])[i], string)
```

?

Comment: And **arrays are not pointers** and **pointers are not arrays** (`const char** additions[]` is not equal to `const char*** additions`)

Comment: Aside from your "is equal to" being quite false, your "so use" is a non sequitur.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys I misread the man page and was searching the substring with the main string

```
char *strcasestr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);
```

Thanks for the answers anyways

Comment: Please post your comments as comments, not answers.

Answer (score 0):

After edit:

---

You are comparing each of "Cream", "Half and half", ... "Kahlua" to "AcceptAdditions: Cream;lots white-sugar;dash\r\n\r\n".

The `strcasestr` will never find a match!

I think you want to break your string in smaller parts and check the little parts.

```
char string[] = "AcceptAdditions: Cream;lots white-sugar;dash\r\n\r\n";
const char *accepted[] = {"cream", "white-sugar", "dash"};
```

and then check each item against each accepted element

```
      for (int k = 0; k < sizeof accepted / sizeof *accepted; k++) {
          if ((ptr = strcasestr((additions[j])[i], accepted[k])) != NULL)
          {
            //ptr += strlen((additions[j])[i]);
            getVolume(ptr);
          }
      }
```